# define r square depending on 1 factor

Tags: r, linear-regression, plyr, r-factor

I get data with one factor. The factor is `ref_fruit`. So my script looks like that to get the R_square for each factor (with MF depending on `heure`) :

```
models <- dlply(P1, "ref_fruit", function(df)
  lm(MF ~ heure, data = df))

ldply(models, coef)
l_ply(models, summary, .print = TRUE)
```

the problem is the list I got with R square is really high each time : around 0.998. This is not what I observed with excel.

And the other problem is I got this message after executing:

```
ldply(models, coef)
```

> Error in fs[[i]](x, ...) : attempt to apply non-function.

May someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost identical to this example for `dplyr` [shown here](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/do.html).  You didn't provide any data but it should be...

```
require(dplyr)
by_fruit <- group_by(df, ref_fruit)
models <- by_fruit %>% do(mod = lm(MF ~ heure, data = .))
models
summarise(models, rsq = summary(mod)$r.squared)
```